# Como pegar um Array em todas as páginas view

Tags: array, mvc, controller

Tenho uma view que é chamada por uma `master page`, o problema é que passo um `array` e a segunda página chamada, mas os dados não chegam conforme esperado.

ex.

```
//controller index
class Index{

public function index(){
$data = array(
'conteudo'=>'index/index', 'teste'=>'teste'

);
$this->view('template', $data);
}

}

//Página view template

$this->view($conteudo);

//segunda view "index/index"

echo $teste <<<< (esta variavel retorna vazia)
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a questão, o teste você passa como chave de um array, depois você tentar dar um echo. Ele vem como key do array, você da um extract em algum momento no conteúdo recebido ($data), se não, de onde vem a variável $teste?

Comment: Está usando algum framework? Qual? Acho que o lógico é enviar novamente a variável $teste pra nova view. Ex.: $this->view($conteudo, compact('teste'));

Comment: estou criando um mini framework -> aqui o repositório
https://github.com/MMS2/dmvc

e sim estou extraindo no core/controller.php

Comment: Tem como colocar um trecho do código do método view? Pois está tudo muito vago. O que você quer é apenas passar um array para um método e deixar os dados do array disponível para os demais métodos?

Comment: Redeclarando a array ele pega, mas gostaria de adicionar automático tipo, só chamo o conteúdo ai ele vem junto. assim não tem como né?

Comment: public function view($view, $data = array()){
$vd = 'app/view/'.$view.'.php';

if(file_exists($vd)){
   $extract = extract($data);
 require_once $vd; 
 return $extract; 
}else{
 
 echo "nao existe o arquivo ".$view." em <b>".$vd."</b>";
}
 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que uma das implementações possíveis ([seguindo como base a documentação informada no comentário onde o fonte está disponibilizado no github](https://github.com/MMS2/dmvc/blob/master/core/controller.php)) que se você transformar o $data em um atributo da classe (tornando ele estático), você conseguiria reutilizar os dados, no exemplo abaixo todo o valor adicionado vai ser armazenado no atributo $data da classe, se o campo já existir ele sobrescreve, se não existir ele cria.

```
<?php

class Controller{
    public $model;
    public $view;
    public static $data = array(); // Alterado

    public function model($model){

        $md = 'app/model/'.$model.'.php';

        if(file_exists($md)){
            require_once $md;   
            return new $model();    
        }else{

            echo "nao existe o arquivo   ".$model." em <b>".$md."</b>";
        }


    }   

    public function view($view, $data = array()){
        $vd = 'app/view/'.$view.'.php';

        if(file_exists($vd)){
            self::$data = array_merge(self::$data, $data); // Alterado
            $extract = extract(self::$data); // Alterado
            require_once $vd;   
            return $extract;    
        }else{

            echo "nao existe o arquivo ".$view." em <b>".$vd."</b>";
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Sileno, Obrigado. Eu havia tentado usar static method... mas sem o array_marge, deu certo =D

Comment: Precisando é só postar que a comunidade ajuda.